# why it doesn't work ? from discord.ext.buttons import Paginator

Tags: python, discord, bots

i have a little problem with replit , i'm trying to make this discord bot and i installed discord and discord.py packages. i tried to install discord-kit package but somehow it says that this package is outdated, anyway the error is when i run the bot i get this error

> File "/home/runner/bot/utils/util.py", line 3, in 
> from discord.ext import Paginator
> ImportError: cannot import name 'Paginator' from 'discord.ext' (unknown location)

and this is the 1st lines of the code :

```
 import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext.buttons import Paginator


class Pag(Paginator):
    async def teardown(self):
        try:
            await self.page.clear_reactions()
        except discord.HTTPException:
            pass
```

Comment: Hello, try fixing your imports like this `from discord.ext import buttons` and class `class Pag(buttons.Paginator)`

Answer (score 1):

The package discord.ext.buttons is recognized as button as in its name, so search for buttons extensions in repl.it and you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Doing `pip install discord-ext-buttons` doesn't work, and it doesn't come default with the discord package.  Typing `pip install buttons` should install it fine, or searching `buttons` in the replit package manager should work.